# Keeping Visual Studio Code Change Markers After Git Commit

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I'm using Visual Studio Code with Git integration, and I really love the feature where modified lines are highlighted with dashed yellow and new lines with green on the left side (near the line numbers). These markers help me keep track of changes I've made to a file.

[image]

However, when I perform a `git add` and `git commit`, these markers disappear, and I lose the visual indication of what has changed since the second to last commit.

[image]

Is there a way to configure VSCode or Git to retain these change markers even after committing, so I can continue to see the differences with respect to the previous version?

Comment: why do I feel like I've seen this exact same question before? is this a repost?

Comment: @starball Can you please share the link? I would delete this question if I find my answer there.

Comment: I don't have the link, though I'll try to search for it. It's just foggy in my memory and I might be misremembering. So it wasn't you I guess.

Comment: the result is that the whole file has green lines